# Numpy turn hierarchy of matrices into concatenation

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have the following 4 matrices:

```
>>> a
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
>>> b
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
>>> c
array([[2., 2.],
       [2., 2.]])
>>> d
array([[3., 3.],
       [3., 3.]])
```

I'm creating another matrix that will contain them:

```
>>> e = np.array([[a,b], [c,d]])
>>> e.shape
(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

**I want to "cancel the hierarchy" and reshape `e` into a 4x4 matrix that will look like this:**

```
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1
2 2 3 3
2 2 3 3
```

However, when I run `e.reshape((4,4))`, I get the following matrix:

```
>>> e.reshape((4,4))
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

Is there a way to reshape my `(2,2,2,2)` matrix into a `(4,4)` matrix by cancelling the hierarchy, rather than the the by the indexing I'm currently getting?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, np arrays are actually flat, the shape consisting of a mapping of the values. Thus I doubt a simple reshaping will do what you want.

Comment: try `np.block([[a,b],[c,d]])`

Comment: @hpaulj that's exactly what I've  been looking for. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
np.block([[a,b],[c,d]])
```

This concatenates the inner lists horizontally, and does a vertical stack.

Alternatively you could swap 2 axes of `e` and then reshape.

```
In [41]: np.block([[a,b],[c,d]])
Out[41]: 
array([[0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.]])

In [45]: e.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[45]: 
array([[0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.]])
```

`block` is doing the equivalent of:

```
In [47]: np.vstack([np.hstack([a,b]),np.hstack([c,d])])
Out[47]: 
array([[0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it with the **`.concatenate`** function of numpy:

```
np.concatenate(np.concatenate(e, axis=1), axis=1)
```

There you get the following matrix as result:

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.],
       [2., 2., 3., 3.]])
```